# VLCJ Get Video Time

Tags: java, vlcj

I have the following code and i want to get the time of my Video but it returns -1. Anyone know why?

```
long video= ourMediaPlayer.getMediaPlayer().getLength();
```

I have tried with getTime() instead of getLength but it returns -1.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, do you want the time or the length? And what do you mean by "time" precisely?

Comment: I found the solution of my problem. I use an EventListener that override the method finish and that help me so much. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

get current video time

```
embeddedMediaPlayer.status().time();
```

get video duration

```
embeddedMediaPlayer.status().length();
```

get current video position

```
embeddedMediaPlayer.status().position()
```

note:my vlcj version is 4.4.4

Answer (score 1):

The `getLength()` method returns -1 if the length is unknown. It depends on the type of media, but sometimes the length is not known until some time after the media starts playing.

Similarly, `getTime()` returns -1 for the time (number of milliseconds from the start of the media) if the time is not known - i.e. if the media has not started playing yet.

This is simply how the underlying native library works, and therefore how vlcj works also.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me >> using Version `4.8.2`

```
embeddedMediaPlayer.media().info().duration();
```

it `returns -1` if it can't get the time and the `long` duration for the video length value.